# How to get the currently selected Value of a MultiColumnComboBox in Kendo for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

here is a working example from the official Telerik team.
https://angular-jo923s.stackblitz.io

When selecting any of the employees, how can I get the `id`(see `contacts.ts`) of the currently selected one, to use it in a different function?

Answer (score 0):

The MultiColumnComboBox has a valueChange event which emits the currently changed item with all of its details. More information can be found here:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/MultiColumnComboBoxComponent/#toc-valuechange

Also here is a quick StackBlitz demo which demonstrates the event in action:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g4pmwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I hop e this helps.